# very weird behaviour of matplotlib with predefined styles on jupyter and on terminal

Tags: matplotlib, plot, python-3.8

I have been banging my head to draw correct plot using the below code. The below code is a piece from a large code.  At some point, I am calling this function with `reg` as the data input (which is very big) to plot it.  When I try the below code on Jupyter it works well. But when I try to it in my pipeline, it does not work.   It simply gives me a normal plot not the seaborn-paper style based.  Any help please

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
f = plt.figure()
f.clear()
plt.clf()
plt.close(f)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(frameon=False)
rc('mathtext',default='regular')
rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.style.use('seaborn-paper')

col = {'sar':'b', 'r':'r'}
pslon_ix = ['sar', 'r']
reg = {'sar':{1:[1,2,3],2:[3,4,5]}, 'r':{1:[1,1,4],2:[1,3,6]}}
labels =  {'sar':'sar', 'r':'r'}

for pslon in pslon_ix:
    cum_reg = [sum(x)/3 for x in zip(*reg[pslon].values())]
    ax.plot(range(3), cum_reg, c=col[pslon], ls='-', label=labels[pslon])
    ax.set_xlabel(r'pslon')
    ax.set_ylabel('cumreg')
    ax.legend()
fig.savefig('sim.pdf',format='pdf')
plt.close()
f = plt.figure()
f.clear()
plt.close(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by using

`with plt.style.context(("seaborn-paper",)):`